# Paypal pro configuration issues in Opecart

Tags: paypal, opencart

I am develop site with `Opencart`. Integrate `PayPal Website Payment Pro` with `test mode`. Select Test Mode yes in admin panel.

But in front side when i go for payment and enter visa card number and other stuff and click confirm payment then display error `This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.`

I follow below steps:

```
Log out Paypal account
clearing browser cache and cookies (I use firefox).
Go to developer.paypal.com and login with the real paypal account (not the Sandbox one)
Go to Applications
Click on Sandbox accounts
(Optional) Import your old accounts from your former Sandbox account after the redirect to the accounts page
Click on the account you want to log in to
Choose Sandbox site
Log in to that site using your test bussiness account
Go to My Profile
In Account information click on Request API Credentials
```

Still i have same issue. Before i got `Secury header is not valid`. I try lots of time but not getting proper mistake.

Comment: Plz help me i also face same problem.. if you find any solution for this problem plz suggest me

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use Sandbox to do testing, there are other alternatives, such as to use another paypal and transact $0.01 via Authorization mode. (This way you can reject the payment)

Try using Paypal Express Checkout instead. All you need to do is to fill up the API credentials and everything will work.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. but i want to integrate credit cards payment instead to redirect on paypal site so....

Comment: Why go for Pro just so it doesn't redirect to Paypal? There's a $30 USD monthly fee as well. Check out the comparisons here: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products

Besides, so what if it redirects you to Paypal? After the transaction is done, user still gets redirected back to your page.

Comment: @Auph plz help i face same problem. i also try PayPal Express Checkout but here is one error "Currency is not supported" if cart price is less

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your Sandbox account to Business Pro.

1. Login to https://developer.paypal.com
2. Go to `Dashboad` and open `Sandbox -> Accounts`
3. Choose an account and click `Profile`
4. On the `Profile` tab click `Upgrade to Pro`.

Note that you should have a Business Sandbox account to be able to upgrade it to pro.